# How to find information about two new Windows updates (3177723 & 3179573) that are not listed at support.microsoft.com

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

My Windows 7 installation told me today that some new updates are available for installation.

One of these updates is 3177723 (listed as "Important"), shown below.

[image: windows update 3177723]

The "More information" link on this update points to [this URL](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3177723).

Another is 3179573 (listed as "Optional"), shown below.

[image: windows update 3179573]

The "More information" link on this second update points to [this URL](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3179573).

Both URLs open a page at support.microsoft.com that says "this page doesn't exist". And a search at support.microsoft.com for either 3177723 or 3179573 does not return any results.

Are there any other avenues through which to find out what problems an update is supposed to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like documentation about 3179573 and 3177723 just appeared online.

The [page about 3179573](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3179573) indicates that it is the "August 2016 update rollup for Windows 7 SP1 and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1".

The [Microsoft KB page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3177723) about 3177723 says:

**2016 — Egypt cancels DST**

Egypt has permanently canceled its observation of daylight savings time (DST). The DST adjustment for this year was scheduled to begin on Friday, July 8, 2016, at midnight (24:00). This change affects the following time zone.

**Time zone key name** **Display name**

Egypt Standard Time (UTC+02:00) Cairo

**Resolution**

The update that is described in this article removes the DST adjustment for Egypt Standard Time starting in 2016.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever the more information link does not work, I wait a few hours or days before applying the update and check it again, sometimes Microsoft is late in posting the webpage. They are now published.

Kb-3177723
"Egypt has permanently canceled its observation of daylight savings time (DST). The DST adjustment for this year was scheduled to begin on Friday, July 8, 2016, at midnight (24:00). This change affects the following time zone."

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3177723

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3179573

also see this for 3179573
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/22801/windows-7-and-windows-server-2008-r2-update-history

[image]